# java regex to replace {var}px with {var} times {var}px

Tags: java, regex, variables

I have the following string:

```
<div height="40px" width="30px" />
```

I would like to replace with regex all the numbers that have px after them with X times their values. (X is a variable).

So if X=3, the result will be

```
<div height="120px" width="90px" />
```

Please note that X must be a variable that I will retrieve to the function

Comment: I think is better if you interpret it as a DOM and read the attributes.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to multiple by x while x is the time which occurs in the string?

Comment: I thought about DOM - but I would like to know if there is a way to do it in REGEX

Comment: @ohyeahchenzai no- I would like to get in the function the X from the user, and multiply each number that has px after it with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code will replace `30px` with `240px` in the String `s` using regular expressions:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abc 30px def";
        int var = 8;

        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)px");
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(s);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s.length());
        while (m.find()) {
            int px = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
            String next = String.valueOf(var * px) + "px";
            m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(next));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Here are the steps it performs:

- Create a compiled regular expression. This improves performance when a regular expression is used again later.
- Search the string `s` for matches and for each match:

  - Convert the string to integer and multiple it by `var`.
  - Append `px` again and pass it as a replacement string.
- Finally, print the input string again with certain strings replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Plain regular expressions cannot *compute*. There are some extensions, for example in Perl, but I don't think they are available in Java. So you will have to go the long way:

- Use regular expression for maching
- Extract value of match
- Build replacement value
- Substitute

Sorry, no one-liner solution available. (But it is not much harder, except that you need a for loop).